# How can I reduce lines in a DataFrame, aggregating identical values in a given column?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

For this question, I will be using the data provided in this [whitespace-delmited file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bly7uyox4qsjbhj/wierda_data.txt).  Please load it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('wierda_data.txt', sep=None)

# For simplicity, let's only consider one subject and one lag
it = iter(ex.groupby(('Subject', 'Lag')))
_, df = it.next()
```

If we take a look at `df.head(10)` we have the following layout:

[image: DataFrame head]

I would like to perform a reduce-type operation so as to have only one row for a given value in the `time` column, averaging the values of `size` and `sizeNB` in the process (zero-values for `T1acc` and `T2acc` will be dropped, so no need to take these into consideration).

To rephrase for clarity, I'd like to collapse rows 79 - 83 into a single row by averaging the values of `size` and `sizeNB`.  *Idem* for the rest of the rows, as per their corresponding `time` values.

My question is therefore twofold:

1. What is the official name of such an operation?  I'm inclined to call it *aggregation over the `time` column*.  Is this correct?
2. How can I do this in pandas?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple to achieve using `groupby` and the `mean` method combined as follows.

You simply `groupby` your `time` column and then apply the `mean` method to each element. See documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('wierda_data.txt', sep=None)

# For simplicity, let's only consider one subject and one lag
it = iter(df.groupby(('Subject', 'Lag')))
_, df = next(it) # _, df = it.next() in Python 2.x

grouped = df.groupby('time').mean()

print(grouped.head(10))
#       Subject  Lag  T1acc  T2acc  NumberOfTargets      size      sizeNB
# time                                                                   
# 20          1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6  0.005682  357.625123
# 40          1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6  0.004841  357.340887
# 60          1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6  0.006504  357.844089
# 80          1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6  0.002467  356.470772
# 100         1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6  0.000210  355.680049
# 120         1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6 -0.002281  354.736782
# 140         1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6 -0.005144  353.849343
# 160         1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6 -0.005076  353.814450
# 180         1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6 -0.008672  352.472578
# 200         1    0    0.6    0.6              0.6 -0.008946  352.473235
```

If you wish to remove the unnecessary data then you can iterate over the columns and delete them from the `grouped` object as below:

```
for column in ['Subject', 'Lag', 'T1acc', 'T2acc', 'NumberOfTargets']:
    del grouped[column]
```

Comment: @Ffsegydd, huh, I should have been able to figure that out myself!  Looks like I was trying to turn something simple into something complicated!  Thanks! =)